# How to listen Table column and current time in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table called users and a column logged_out_time. If the current time is equal to logged_out_time i need to run some script. I am so confused to use delayed_job. So kindly give me some ideas.

Comment: i didnt try delayed job. i had a doubt that with delayed job. will delayed job listen table column?

Comment: What do you mean by "If the current time is equal to logged_out_time"?

Comment: my logged_out_time is 20:00 hrs. Current time is 18::00 hrs. If current time reaches 20:00 hrs i need to change the users status. This logged_out_time will very for each user.

Comment: Do you need to run this script exactly when the condition happens? Can the script wait a while to be run?

Comment: i need to run the script at the exact time. please suggest some idea or gem

Comment: why dont u look at writing cron jobs http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Well, using just Rails it is not possible to accomplish. You need to use a background processing tool. So, to understand it better, imagine you have another application which has access to your records. You can program it to run some code every x amount of time (it could be seconds, minutes or scheduled times during the day). For that you can use [delayed-jobs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised), [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or a lot more.

But your scheduled time is variable, and every new user that logs in, you have a new logout_time saved and you'll have to run the script for that guy too. It is very complicated to maintain, think about it. I'm not saying it's impossible. For example, you can try to do that like:

1. Every time a user logs in, you'll save a logout_time for him.
2. Right after this, call a method in a service class to run the code you want.
3. Send this job to the queue. In delayed-job it would be:

   ```
   def process

   end
   # 8.hours.from_now will be evaluated when process is called
   handle_asynchronously :process, :run_at => Proc.new { 8.hours.from_now }
   ```

If the interval of time varies for each user, you can do the same thing using `.delay` when calling your method.  Also, you can accomplish that (the same 3 steps) using [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

How do you know exactly when users log out? For example users close their browser or shutdown the PC, how can you handle these events?

However, assume that you can control the user log out event. I think you need a realtime application. You can give a try with [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) gem or using [Redis and Nodejs](https://github.com/thoughtshop/rails-node-redis-pubsub) for realtime app

Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: that logged_out_time is calculated from logged_in_time. i.e logged_in_time + 8

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you know in advance when an event occurs.
If user logs out at 20:00 or any other time you need to delay job like
 `.delay(run_at: 24.hours.from_now)`. If user logged in in this period just ensure that the current time equal to delayed inside action.